# Specify number of filter banks in Librosa MFCC

Tags: python, librosa, mfcc

How can you specify the number of filter banks in Librosa MFCC feature?:

```
librosa.feature.mfcc(y=None, sr=22050, S=None, n_mfcc=20, dct_type=2, norm='ortho', lifter=0, **kwargs)
```

From the documentation, `n_mfcc` is the number of MFCCs.  Is that the same as the number of filter banks?

Comment: @JonNordby, thanks for your response.  To confirm, `n_mels` then is the number of filters? Also, as a side question, `n_mfcc` is the number of MFC coefficients?

Comment: Yes that is correct :)